# Работа с USB клавиатурным считывателем

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.
Подcкажите в какую сторону копать с USB считывателем магнитных карт в Андроиде? 
Как обработать информацию с него при считывании карты? Или как обработать нажатия с USB клавиатуры?

Comment: Обработка нажатий происходит стандартно, главное чтобы девайс поддерживал usb otg

Comment: Обработка нажатий происходит стандартно, главное чтобы девайс поддерживал usb otg т.е. для начала на активити создаете EditText, переводите туда фокус, включаете usb считыватель, читаете карту или что там у вас, в editText появится считанная строка

Comment: А что значит стандартно, как и от виртуальной клавиатуры? Так просто что-ли?

Comment: Да, все просто. Можно заморочиться с отловом нажатия клавишь и тд. Но суть одна - usb otg и работа как с обычной клавой

Comment: Я делал нечто похожее - https://youtu.be/8GExv6lKHuc там все просто

Comment: Да сканер мне тоже нужен, огромное спасибо всем. Работает на ура. Я блин SDK уже обыскался для считывателей :-)